# Home folder doesn't update or show newly added users

Tags: 11.04, adduser

I am having a very big problem and that is, whenever I add a new user (via command line with `adduser krishna` command) the user is created but it's home folder or it's own private folder isn't created but some times it works (tried 15 times worked 3 times) so please can anyone help me out. One more thing it creates the user account but doesn't create it's folder, please help me am a newbie in Ubuntu.

Output:-
Nothing just the newline & waiting for the next command..When it didn't create any folder, but when the folder was too created, it asked for unix password, retype password, full name, work, and 2 more options.

Comment: `useradd username` will not create a homedir by default, and will not output anything; just create the user. `adduser username` will ask you questions about the new user, such as the real name, what password to set etc. Make sure you use `adduser`, not `useradd`.

Comment: geirha and MacroCeppi thank you very much i've got it, i guess i would have misprinted it, anyways thank you for ur help and precious time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear as though you're using `useradd` and not `adduser`. The former will simply create a user account in the `/etc/passwd` file and nothing more (unless you use the `-m` flag, or use `-D`), this command also outputs nothing when it successfully completes. The latter (`adduser`) is the one that prompts for additional information, including password, and GECOS information. Make sure you use this command going forward unless you wish to modify the defaults for which a user's account is created.

Comment: @MacroCeppi actually i was confused with userdel and keeping this command in mind i typed useradd..

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat In that respect, you may wish to use `deluser` going forward, as it'll also clean up the home folder and everything else `adduser` creates :)

Comment: oh thank you i'll keep that in mind while deleting a user =)